# What is the equivalent of Python's list[:x] in C++?

Tags: python, c++, list, vector

In Python, if I have some list L and I want the first x elements of it, I call L[:x].

In C++, I use vectors instead, but I don't know of any easy way to invoke the first x elements of the vector.

Comment: You can do it with a [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), using the [`splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways:

1) Create a vector `v` consisting of first `x` elements as:

```
 std::vector<T>  v { begin(L), begin(L) + x };
```

2) Pass first `x` elements to a function, as pair of iterators:

```
 f(begin(L), begin(L) + x);
```

where `f` accepts two iterators as arguments — explore the [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) from `<algorithm>`, as almost all of them work on pair of iterators.

Depending on your use case, you could use any of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use boost then boost range has [boost::slice](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html); which is quite similar to python:

```
auto first_x = L | sliced(0, x);
```

Also see the full example on their documentation page:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/sliced.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    using namespace boost::assign;

    std::vector<int> input;
    input += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;

    boost::copy(
        input | sliced(2, 5),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));

    return 0;
}

// 3,4,5,
```